How do I retrieve the cloud key of my Digital Ocean Perforce Helix Core droplet?
I just finished creating a Perforce Helix Core Digital Ocean droplet, and I'm now trying to retrieve the default credentials in order to get started with it.
Following the instructions, I need to SSH into the instance, and the instructions specify a "cloud key". How do I get this cloud key?

Alternatively, I tried logging into the droplet console via the web interface, but I only get stuck on a "Waiting for console" screen.

The part that says your-cloud-key is talking about the private SSH key that you created earlier in the process. The digitalocean instructions should have had you use your terminal to create an SSH key and then input the public key into digitalocean. So you'll use the private key to connect via SSH.
As for the issue with the web terminal telling you to wait, I have run into issues when using the smallest instance type on DO where it will have trouble booting up the first time because the memory is so low. But I have found that just restarting the instance fixes it.
So give it a try by restarting from the digitalocean dashboard and then see if you can connect with the web console.

That is totally it! I didn't realize it was referring to the local path of my private key file. Seems like I'm able to SSH in now, I'm just stuck with a "Helix Core is being configured. Try again in a few moments..." message.
I'll give it another try in a "few moments." Thank you!

Generate a new SSH Key Pair in the terminal with:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 ~/.ssh/new-cloudDigital-key
Add the public key ~/.ssh/new-cloudDigital-key.pub (ensure extension .pub) in the Digital Ocean.
Lets me know if it's fixed
